# What should the end-user expect after a cross contract call failure

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cross-contract-call

I was attempting to comprehend the workings of cross-contract calling in substrate ink contracts using this particular sample code.

If I provide `u64::MAX` as the `calls_count` value, it will result in a failure, what should the end user expect to receive when invoking the test_cross_contract_call function?

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn test_cross_contract_call(&mut self, callee: AccountId, calls_count: u64) {
            let selector: Selector = Selector::new([0x6b, 0x25, 0xcb, 0x19]);
            let response: u64 = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(
                    Call::new()
                        .callee(callee)
                        .transferred_value(0)
                        .gas_limit(50000),
                )
                .call_flags(ink::env::CallFlags::default().set_allow_reentry(true))
                .exec_input(ExecutionInput::new(selector).push_arg(calls_count))
                .returns::<u64>()
                .invoke();
            self.value = response;
}

#[ink(message, selector = 0x6b25cb19)]
pub fn dummy_function(&mut self, value: u64) -> u64 {
            return 45 * value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `dummy_function` is going to overflow because `n * u64::MAX > u64`, meaning your contract will trap.

Since you're using [`CallBuilder::invoke()`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.0.1/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.invoke-2), which panics upon any encountering any error, your caller contract will also trap.

If you want to attempt to handle errors you'll need to use [`CallBuilder::try_invoke()`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.0.1/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.try_invoke-2) instead.

I assume you'll get a [`CalleeTrapped`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/4.0.1/ink_env/call/struct.CallBuilder.html#method.try_invoke-2) error due to the overflow, but I haven't tried it out myself.